# Content Query WebPart & Date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

```
<xsl:template name="TitleDate" match="Row[@Style='TitleOnly']" mode="itemstyle">
        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
                <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="DisplayDueDate">
         <xsl:value-of select="@TaskDueDate" />
        </xsl:variable>
      <div class="item link-item">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
        <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle "/>
        </a>
        <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayDueDate" />
      </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have this code that gives me the Title and Date of all tasks. My question is how would I format the date?

This is what it looks like formatted.

AU

2014-07-30 00:00:00

Also is there a way to make this into a column instead of one under the other?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your desired output format, but an example would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@Created, 1033, 'MMMM d, yyyy')" />
```

This should still apply to 2013.

Kyle links to some useful resources in [this post](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-item-styles-and-ddwrt/), like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.95).aspx) and Heather Solomon.

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime this website doesn't work it says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."